# How to check whether current LDAP server is up or down before doing an authentication

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I want to check whether the current LDAP server is up or down before doing an authentication. I am using UnboundID LDAP SDK. IS there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with SSUtil. Here an authenticated entry will not be needed and we can check whether the server is up or down before doing any authentication.

```
SSLUtil su = new SSLUtil(new TrustAllTrustManager());
SSLSocketFactory sf = su.createSSLSocketFactory();
LDAPConnection connection = new LDAPConnection(sf,"localhost", 10636);
```

Looking for pros and cons for this solution.

Comment: Con: you're trying to predict the future. The server could be up when you do the test and down when you do the authentication. Or the other way round. There's no point to this.

Comment: What do you mean by predicting the future. Just I need to check whether the server is up or down before doing any authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the port is up and running. It's pur Java. No SSL Factory or SSL Context or Credentials needed. Has a time out in milliseconds, if the package is dropped by a firewall.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public static boolean isPortReachable(String host, int port, int timeOutMS) {
    try (Socket serverSocket = new Socket();) {
        serverSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeOutMS);
        return true;    
    } catch (final IOException e) { /* Ignore, Port not reachable */ }
    return false;
}
```

Usage for LDAP or LDAPS:

```
if (isPortReachable(hostname, 389, 200)) { ... }

if (isPortReachable(hostname, 636, 200)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method isConnected():

```
public boolean isConnected()
Indicates whether this connection is currently established.
Returns:
true if this connection is currently established, or false if it is not.
```

So a simple example something like:

```
LDAPConnection ldc = new LDAPConnection()
ldc.connect(...);
if (ldc.isConnected())
{
   do good stuff
}
else
{
   getLDAPConnection(...);
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: I need to know whether LDAP server is down or up before doing any authentication. In this answer I have to use an authenticated entry to create ldc connection. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this would work as required. I would expect it not to actually connect until you did some real LDAP operation.

Comment: The ldc.isconnected actually does a connection. As I recall, makes an 
anonymous call to some non-existent control or extension

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test whether any resource is available is simply to try to use it in the normal course of your application, and cope with the errors as they arise.

Otherwise you're trying to predict the future.